# HTMX not sending request to server?

Tags: html, http, htmx

So I wrote my own minimalist server and I'm trying to host an HTMX site on it to play around with. I wrote the server from scratch in C using the UNIX socket api and it is working to handle HTTP requests, but when I try to send a request with an HTMX element it is never even sent to the server.

I trouble shoot, I also tried running a server on Python, which I know should work, using 'python3 -m http.server 8000', and my HTMX elements actually do function, but the server is not receiving any requests from them. I can tell this because they python server (and my own server) print out the requests as they are received.

I also have an anchor tag to send the same request I want from the HTMX element (a GET request for the file blog.html), and this is working on both servers (although with the python server it caches the file so the request is only sent to the server the first time.)

Here is my HTMX code.

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Sweet webpage.</title>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/htmx.org@1.9.9" integrity="sha384-QFjmbokDn2DjBjq+fM+8LUIVrAgqcNW2s0PjAxHETgRn9l4fvX31ZxDxvwQnyMOX" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My sweet webpage.</h1>
        <p>Welcome.</p>
        <a href="/blog.html">Blog</a>
        <button
            hx-get="/blog.html"
            hx-trigger="click"
        >To the blog!
        </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Like I said, when the link is clicked, a 'GET /blog.html' request is sent to the server (and handled) for both the python server and my own server, but when the button element is clicked, there is no request sent for either server. With the python server, the element behaves as expected and the contents of the button change, but on my own server nothing happens.

THanks

Comment: Please share your server code, if possible. tx